# How do I choose a graphics card which balances CPU?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, compatibility

I just heard from one of my friend that I cannot buy a high end graphics card if I don't have a high end processor. Now, my problem how do I make sure that a graphics card say, GTX 780 will work with what CPU? I haven't decided on what kind of processor I want but I think this is a kind of general question: How do you know what processor can support a particular graphics card. Shouldn't this be like mentioned on the card's box? Where and how else I can check?

Comment: Don't listen to your friend, they are wrong, they are not even remotely correct.  Based on what they told you, never trust what they tell you, they clearly know nothing about technology.

Comment: So, Can I happily get any card with PCIe x16 regardless of what CPU I have? Thanks

Comment: In the PC world, you should be able combine any CPU with a GPU that the motherboard supports.  There is a sensibility aspect, that the system should be balanced for performance (e.g. using slow RAM with a fast CPU is wasteful).  I have combined a less-powerful CPU with a better GPU to handle the video decoding chores.  But I had to be careful to not go too far down in CPU performance because these AMD processors also had integrated memory controllers.  In that situation the slower CPUs had slower memory channels to affect overall system throughput.

Comment: @Aaron What does your research show?

Comment: Well, my research shows pretty much what @sawdust already said. But again, my question how do I find a GPU that balances with CPU? Because I don't know any tool to match it.

Comment: Would be quite helpful if you added details of your proposed setup

Answer (score 1):

Graphics cards/GPUs have *nothing* to do with your processor/CPU.  They are completely independent of each other.

Your friend might be confusing terms.  Some people erroneously call the computer, as a whole, a CPU.  However, that is completely wrong.  The CPU is a chip on the motherboard, inside the case.

Graphics cards/GPUs do have different bus types.  In layman's terms, this means the slot on the graphics card has to match the socket on the motherboard.  Here is a decent [write up](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-pci-express/4/) on different PCIe connectors.

You can look at your computer's manual, or google the model to find out what your computer supports.  *Generally* you will find at least one PCIe x16 on most motherboards.  That is what most high end graphics cards use.

Its also important to note that your power supply might not have the connectors, or even the power, needed for a GTX780.  High end cards require more power than the motherboard provides, so there are special power connectors.  The power supply might need to be replaced, depending on what you have in your PC.

Comment: Why is it often said that the processor will be a bottleneck if doesn't measure up well with GPUs performance?

Comment: I have never heard anyone say that.

Comment: Here for example at know your bottlenecks section: http://www.pcgamer.com/how-to-buy-a-graphics-card-six-things-you-must-know-about-gpus/

Comment: @Aaron lol. They are taking about 20 year old processors. You have nothing to worry about.